# What is this Component and how does it differ from others

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm self-teaching React and was just wondering if someone could clear something up for me.

I have this component, which seems to be doing everything I need it to:

```
const Projects = ({ projectData }) => {

  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (

    {projectData.map((project) => (

          <div className="project-container" key={project.id}>
            <div className="project-image">
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>{project.name}</h2>
              <p>{project.description}</p>
              <div>
                <Button class="button link_right relative" linkTo={`${url}/${project.id}`} btnText="Explore" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        ))}

  );
};

export default Projects;
```

While watching tutorials and reading documentation I'll typically see Function and Class Components but not whatever this is:

`const ComponentName = () => {`

So, my questions are:

- What sort of component is my example known as
- What purpose does it
  serve when compared to a Function Component or a Class Component,
- How would a Function Component or a Class Component need to look in
  order to do everything that my example component is currently doing.

Thanks!

Comment: your component is functional component. I recommend reading about the difference between functional components and class Component: https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components

Answer (score 0):

Making instance of class is too slow, because of calling constructor and inheritance. Functional components are just functions, there are no such overheads.

In addition, there is how to treat `this`. In class, entity of `this` is often unclear and that confused us. Arrow function reduce it, but using class, we must use `this`. `this` caused complicated management of state too. And class object has state itself, so it was troublesome.

Function, defined carefully, is easy to keep purity. It has no state itself. It means that state management is not bother us. Data flow is cleared.